# How to manage same item with different URL per language version?

Tags: multilingual

In `Sitecore 7.5`, it keeps the Item name same across all the language versions

So it is like

**For the English language:** http://example.com/products/accessories

**For German language:** http://example.com/de-de/products/accessories

Is possible out-of-the-box or by some customization in Sitecore to be able to create different URL per language for the same item as below?

**Required for German language:** http://example.com/de-de/produkte/zubehoer

The site is sharing the same content tree across all languages, so having different content tree per language is not a good option here for me. Also, don't want to use Sitecore Alias due to large number of pages we have in the site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can configure the `LinkManager` to use Display Name instead of item title when generating URLs.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
      <providers>
        <add name="sitecore">
          <patch:attribute name="useDisplayName">true</patch:attribute>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The items will still resolve using the title though, so you would probably want to implement redirects to the localized url or use canonical URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate field to store the localizable name and then override `GetItemPathElement` in `LinkBuilder` class to use the new field.

As a bonus you can add option to control use of this field through the configuration (in a similar way @Kasper Gadensgaard suggested to choose using display name).

Comment: `GetItemPathElement` is in `LinkBuilder` not in `LinkProvider`

Comment: @HarshBaid you're right, thanks for pointing this out. This class is in the same file as `LinkProvider`